Select all rows leading to the first occurrence
I have the following table
DECLARE @mytable TABLE ([userid] integer, [outcome] varchar(max), id int)  

INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (101, 'start', 1)  
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (101, 'sold', 2)  
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (101, 'return', 3)  
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (101, 'sold', 4)  
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (102, 'start', 1)  
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (102, 'call', 2)  
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (102, 'mailer', 3)  
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (103, 'start', 1)  
INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES (103, 'mailer', 2)  

--SELECT max([userid]) FROM @mytable where [outcome] = 'sold'

SELECT *  
FROM @mytable 

I want to select all events for each userid that led to the first sold
In this data, only 101 has a sale.
So the output should be
101    start
101    sold

These don't seem to work...
SELECT *  
FROM @mytable 
WHERE [userid] > (SELECT MAX([userid]) 
                  FROM @mytable 
                  WHERE [outcome] = 'sold') 

SELECT *  
FROM @mytable  
WHERE [outcome] > (SELECT MAX([outcome]) 
                   FROM @mytable 
                   WHERE [outcome] = 'sold')


it is not possible if you table does not contains a column that can use to identify the sequence of event

You first need to add a column that defines an unambiguous order of the data (at least for each ID). This might be an ordinal column, sequentially generated row number, or a unique date/time stamp. (SQL tables do not have an implicit row order.) Next you can use Get top 1 row of each group logic to select the first "sold" row for each userid. Once you have selected those rows, join back to your original data for matching userid and ordinal <= first sold ordinal.

I note you haven't accepted an answer to your recent questions - is there a reason for that?

Your request seems not quite clear as it will not look at possible 'return' events making a previous 'sold' worthless. It will also only list one 'sold' event per userid. But if we can treat the id as a sequence indicator per userid which it appears to be (from looking at the data) you could do a query like
SELECT t.* FROM @mytable t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT userid uid, MIN(id) sid FROM @mytable WHERE outcome='sold' GROUP BY userid) s
ON uid=userid AND sid>=id

to get the result you described in your question.
I prepared a little (modified) demo here:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1866406

the answer I gave was wrong after all. See also this fiddle IT seems this answer also is giving wrong results when you alter the data a little bit

EDIT : I corrected the error in my first attempt, it will now show correct values even if the second row has a different value than 'sold'
Another option is to use an outer apply
see this dbfiddle
select mt.userid,
       t.outcome
from   mytable mt
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       t.outcome  
                from   mytable t
                where  t.userid = mt.userid
                order by t.id
                union all
                select t.outcome
                from   mytable t
                where  t.userid = mt.userid
                and    t.id = mt.id
              ) t
where  mt.outcome = 'sold'  
group by mt.userid, t.outcome
order by t.outcome desc

The where mt.outcome = 'sold' and the group by make sure I only get 'sold' rows
The outer apply then retrieves the first row from each sold group and the actual 'sold' row
The result is



userid
outcome




101
start


101
sold




This does not satisfy the OPs requirements.  The logic will select all "sold" rows, plus the first row (lowest id) for each userid. The presence of multiple selected "sold" rows is obfuscated by the group-by. If there are multiple actions before the first sold, all but the first will be omitted. See this fiddle that includes extra test data and a slight modification that shows the id values of the selected rows.

@TN Then why does he has that expected outcome in his question then ? My answer returns exact that, if that is not what he want he should be more clear about it

@TN I added the data that you added in your fiddle, and it seems to me my answer still gives out what he wants in his expected outcome. dbfiddle here

I guess we have different interpretations of "all events for each userid that led to the first sold". As I read it, if the "first sold" were the 4th row in the series for a given userid, the results should include the first 4 rows leading up to that first "sold" row. For the data in your latest fiddle, I would expect: 101: start > soldtest > return > sold and 901: start > other1 > other2 > sold. I believe Carsten Massmann's answer does precisely that.

@TN But it is not what the OP has in his expected outcome. My answer does that, so it is indeed depending on how you interpret the question

I think this returns all the rows for the userid up to the first 'sold' outcome. This means only userid's with at least 1 sold outcome are included.
fiddle
select F1.* from mytable F1
join 
  (  select o.userid,min(o.id) as colx from mytable o where o.outcome='sold' group by o.userid
  ) F2
on F2.userid = F1.userid
where F1.id <= F2.colx

But it has ended up almost the same as @Carsten Massmann
= = =
Thanks @GuidoG for your comment. My first answer was wrong which I realise now. I will leave that wrong answer below. It only returned the first sold row.
SELECT F1.* FROM mytable F1
  where userid in (
  select userid from mytable where outcome = 'sold' )
  and concat(userid,id) in (
  select concat(userid,min(id)) from mytable where outcome='sold' group by userid
  )
order by userid,id

dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/6lYBTYna

in your dbfiddle the result is not even close to what the OP asked, so maybe you should explain this answer

Hi @GuidoG I have fixed my answer - thanks for your comment.  But I have ended up with the same as Carsten Massmann
